# How to close accordion element before opening another accordion text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually i have implemented Accordion using bootstrap classes It is working fine while we click on More Info.But If i click on Next accordion text the first one should close automatically.Can any one help me this.Thanks In advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion" >More Info</div>
                    <div class="panel">
        <p>            
        Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion" >More Info</div>
                    <div class="panel">
        <p>            
        Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
display: none;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
 }

     div.panel.show {
display: block;
color: #2b3034;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
margin-left: -18px;
border-radius: 0px;
width: 778px;
margin-top: 16px;
background: #ffffff;
margin-bottom: -17px;
              }
```

Javascript:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
 }
 }
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mveau1v4)**

Comment: Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/mveau1v4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to track the previously expanded accordion e.g:

```
var currentActive; // track the current active accordion.
```

and close it when another one is expanded,

```
var toggleAccordionState = function(accordion) {
      accordion.classList.toggle("active");
      accordion.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
};

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        if(currentActive) {
                toggleAccordionState(currentActive);  //Close the current accordion.
        }
        toggleAccordionState(this);
        currentActive = this;     // Save the current open accordion   
  }
```

see the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mveau1v4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Since You have tagged Jquery tag .Just add `$(".panel").removeClass("show");`

```
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function(){

            $(".panel").removeClass("show");
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
      }
    }
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mveau1v4/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

**In Your Code You Selected Accordions Based On Class Name , And One More Thing At All The Time Its Not A Correct Process, You Should Select That Item Based On Separate Id Then It Will Works Perfectly .**

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with jQuery by doing something simple like this:

Here a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mveau1v4/5/

```
var acc = jQuery(".accordion");

acc.on("click", function(){
    //remove status from past elements
    $(".show").removeClass("show");
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    //add new status to the clicked element.
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).next(".panel").addClass("show");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is better approach by tweaking your HTML so that we can move the expand logic to the CSS. This will trim down one call on the JS. Anyway, to help you understand more how it works, I updated your JS based on our style. Hope it helps.

```
   var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
   var showMore = function(){
       hideOthers();
       this.classList.toggle('active');
       this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
   };

   var hideOthers = function(){
       var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion active");
       for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
           elements[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show');
           elements[i].classList.toggle('active');
       } 
   }
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kye6px4m/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version that worked for me. Hopefully others can use it.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;  // Collapse clicked panel
    } 
    else { // expand clicked panel
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        collapseOthers(this);
    } 
    }
}

// Collapse all other accordions except the clicked one
function collapseOthers(clickedAccor) {
    var accs = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    for (var i = 0; i < accs.length; i++) {
        if (accs[i] != clickedAccor) {
           accs[i].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
        }
    }
}
```